# Do keepalives to socket connections exist?

Tags: linux, nginx, tcpip, socket, keepalive

***Pre briefing:***

Although my question is broad on purpose, I am dealing with nginx connecting to php-fpm (fcgi), which is served via a local socket (/tmp/somesocket.socket).

Nginx has a setting to keepalive connections to fcgi backends ( http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_keep_conn ).

This is what my question relates to.

***Question:***

In linux, when making connection to local sockets, does such a thing as keepalives exist?

Would having a connection kept alive remove (even a tiny bit) some overhead related to creation / teardown of the connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you mean local unix sockets here.

> In linux, when making connection to local sockets, does such a thing as keepalives exist?

No, keepalives prevent the remote side timing out. Since the host knows the status of both sides of the connection a keepalive is redundant.

> Would having a connection kept alive remove (even a tiny bit) some overhead related to 
>   creation / teardown of the connection?

Yes, at the cost of maintaining more file descriptors which is probably a very cheap cost in practical terms. Setting up a connection and closing it incurs 5 system calls (open and connect on client, accept on server, close on client/server) which with maintaining the connection is avoided until necessary.